# Creating popup window with a text input for CakePHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.8 and I want to create a popup upon clicking a link that will have a textxbox input. For example, click a refund button/link, and then a popup appears with an input for the refund amount.

I know how to make confirmation boxes from a link, but I have no idea how to add a text box to it or how to modify it in any way. Ex:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Something', array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'dosomething', 6),array(),"Are you sure you wish to do something?");
```

Can I do this with the form helper, or is it something I need JavaScript/jQuery for?

**edit I called a friend and he figured it out. He wasn't sure how to do it with the linkhelper, but was able to do it with the formhelper.**

```
echo $this->Form->create('refund',array('onsubmit'=>'return prompt("Refund Value");'));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [Cake DOCs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html), all the Cake form helper does is help you create javascript on the server side which will then be created on the client side.

All in all it will work out better if you write your own javascript than if you rely on Cake's functions in which you basically **write** javascript into PHP function which will then output to the client anyway.

Comment: Of course it creates it on the server side, but I don't see how that's relevant. If the form/link helper can create confirmation boxes, I'm asking if it can also create one with a textbox. Why write extra code when Cake can do it for you?

Comment: I am sure it can, but I do not see the real point in using server side code to create code that will run on the client side.

Comment: Cake cannot do it for you! You have to inject the javascript functions that you want to use into the Cake form functions which is very silly and backwards

Comment: Why? There's absolutely no difference, it just means less coding overall. That's the whole point of the form/html helper

Comment: @Neal I called a friend and he figured it out. It is possible, contrary to what you believe. See my edited post.

Comment: All you did was pass a javascript function to a PHP function... I do not see the point... Also please do not update your question with an answer in the future...

Comment: @Neal You don't see the point to what? It accomplishes exactly what I was asking.